# Replacing string with a variable in php

Tags: php, string, wordpress, variables

I have following code in my plugin of Wordpress:

```
wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue[idinfo],
            'index1' => $myoptionValue[id1],
            'index2' => $myoptionValue[id2]
            )
        );
```

I want to replace

```
'index1' => $myoptionValue[id1],
'index2' => $myoptionValue[id2]
```

with

```
for($i=1; $i<= $myoptionValue[fieldcount]; $i++)
        {
            $arguments .= ',"index"'.$i.'=>'.$myoptionValue[id.$i];
        }
```

So that I have

```
        wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue[idinfo]
            $arguments
            )
        );
```

Apparently I'm thinking it might be as simple as this, but it isn't, where is my mistake?

EDIT:

Full (working) code:

```
require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'menu.php');
    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'getuser.php');

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ffd_load_scripts' );

    function ffd_load_scripts()
    {
        $myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
        $myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );  

        wp_register_script('ffd_js_script', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/FixFormData/js/ffd_js_script.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_localize_script('ffd_js_script', 'myAjax', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'idinfo' => $myoptionValue[idinfo],
            'index1' => $myoptionValue[id1],
            'index2' => $myoptionValue[id2]
            )
        );

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('ffd_js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ffd_js_script.js');
```

Comment: Don't patch together PHP code to inject. You are looking for [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) or just `+`. And quote your literal array keys, btw.

Comment: could you give an example? What do you mean with the literal array keys?

Comment: Hello? I can't get it to work and this can't be that hard

Comment: You want your $arguments variable to be an array, correct? Right now I believe you have created a string rather than an array. I believe that is what mario was alluding to.

Comment: I have edited my OP with full code